# Rails Grape API include module - Zeitwerk::NameError - expected file to define constant, but didn't:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-grape, grape-api

I want to make a small code refactor and extract client external client from gem to a separate module (it's use to connect to the DatoCMS API via `gem 'dato'`). My standard class, which works well, look like:

`app/services/receive_webhook/fetch_model_name.rb`

```
module ReceiveWebhook
  class FetchModelName
    def initialize(model_id)
      @model_id = model_id
    end

    def call
      fetch_model(@model_id).dig('name')
    end

    private

    def client
      @client ||= Dato::Site::Client.new(Rails.application.credentials.datocms_api_token)
    end

    def fetch_model(model_id)
      client.item_types.find(model_id)
    end
  end
end
```

I want to separate `client` method to a different module and include it in `FetchModelName` class (like in standard Rails app). To do so I use below code:

`app/dato_cms_api/dato_client.rb`

```
module DatoCmsApi
  module DatoClient
    def client
      @client ||= Dato::Site::Client.new(Rails.application.credentials.datocms_api_token)
    end
  end
end
```

With updated `FetchModelName` class:
`app/services/receive_webhook/fetch_model_name.rb`

```
module ReceiveWebhook
  class FetchModelName
    include ::DatoClient

    def initialize(model_id)
      @model_id = model_id
    end

    def call
      fetch_model(@model_id).dig('name')
    end

    private

    def fetch_model(model_id)
      client.item_types.find(model_id)
    end
  end
end
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
Zeitwerk::NameError - expected file app/dato_cms_api/dato_client.rb to define constant DatoClient, but didn't:
  app/services/receive_webhook/fetch_model_name.rb:5:in `<class:FetchModelName>'
  app/services/receive_webhook/fetch_model_name.rb:4:in `<module:ReceiveWebhook>'
  app/services/receive_webhook/fetch_model_name.rb:3:in `<main>'
  app/controllers/api/v1/webhooks/dato_cms/receive_webhook.rb:29:in `block in <class:ReceiveWebhook>'
```

Does Grape API not support include module practice?

Comment: I am afraid if you have missed top level module while using include. Seems like you need to try defining `include ::DatoCmsApi::DatoClient`

Comment: naah, forgot to add this but with `::DatoCmsApi::DatoClient` I've got an error `> uninitialized constant DatoCmsApi
Did you mean?  DatoClient`

Comment: Ahh, got it then. Just remove `module DatoCmsApi` and every thing should work perfectly.

Comment: But this is in a different folder than `FetchModelName` class. It's in `app/dato_cms_api/...` so this folder called `dato_cms_api` shouldn't be reflected in module?

Comment: Any new folder/directory inside app directory is not considered as module. After that if you need directory inside directory, then you need to consider it as module.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to downgrade your autoloader to classic?
In your `application.rb` file, add this:

```rb
config.autoloader = :classic
```